# Rails mongodb - set today's date in field :date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'd like to automaticaly add the today's date for the :date field of my controller.
I'm new with Rails and have no idea how to set this default value, except that it must be in the controller.

Here is my Post model :

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :text, type: String
  field :date, :type => DateTime
end
```

And my Post controller :

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end 

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text, :date)
end
```

Looking in Rails docs, I read about Date.current or Date.today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting default values in your class, as @T J suggested would do the trick.

But if you want to set the default value only in an specific view, let's say your 'posts/create' view, you could use this in your correspoding action:

```
    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.date ||= Date.today
      .
      .
      .
    end
```

The syntax:

```
     @post.date ||= Date.today
```

is a short cut for

```
    @post.date = @post.date || Date.today
```

Answer (score 6):

You could always let Mongoid handle the default value for you

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  field :text, type: String
  field :date, :type => DateTime, default: ->{ Date.today }
end
```

This way, if date is nil in your params, it will get set to the todays date.

Default values are documented [here.](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, I'd like to add that in some cases you can use the Timestamps module by simply including to your model:

```
include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
```

Answer (score 0):

I encounter a similar problem. It needs to set Time.zone.now to default time when expired_at not have value, for example:

```rb
class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :expired_at, type: DateTime, default: Time.zone.now
end
```

It does not work when the codes are deployed in staging.
I research the problem and find the answer in mongoid manual document [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-documents/#defaults).

```rb
  field :dob, type: Time, default: Time.zone.now # first
  field :dob, type: Time, default: -> { Time.zone.now } # second
```

For default time, it has two formats, The second is defined in lambdas or procs, and the first is not. But they are not equivalent.

The first is evaluated at class load time, and the second is evaluated at document creation time.

I should use the second, as follow:

```rb
class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :expired_at, type: DateTime, default: -> { Time.zone.now }
end
```

You also should use the second, as follow:

```rb
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :date, type: Date,  default: -> { Date.today }
end
```